# How Do I Return Statements Located in If Conditionals (Processing)

Tags: if-statement, processing

I am making an integer called bondPositionCounter that is supposed to return an integer based on conditions where one of the two conditions in if statements are met. However, even if one of those conditions is true, the integer method always returns  1. Without the final return line, I get an error claiming that the method must return something of type int. Why is that?

---

My code is below.

```
    int bondPositionCounter(int i, int j) { 
    if ((g.grid.cells[i][j].isOccupied == true) && (g.grid.cells[i + 1][j].isOccupied == true)) {
      g.grid.bondsh[i][j].bondUsage = true;
      return 8 * i + j;
    } else if ((g.grid.cells[i][j].isOccupied == true) && (g.grid.cells[i][j + 1].isOccupied == true)) {
      g.grid.bondsv[i][j].bondUsage = true;
      return 56 + 8 * i + j;
    }
    return 1; 
  }
```

Comment: In the case of a series of `if`-`else if` statments, the compiler has no way of knowing if *all* of them could be false. If that happens, it would reach the end of the method without returning a value, which violates its contract. So, in this case, your `return 1` happens only if your two if's are false. It would be semantically equivalent to end the `if/else-if` block with an `else` clause that returned a value as well, in which case you could remove the free-standing `return 1` and the compiler would be happy.

Comment: @aruisdante Post as answer so that we can vote.

Comment: If your intention is *not* for there to be a default return value, you could instead raise an `Exception` (I'd link, but you don't specify language and you could be either C/C++ or Java based on code) as the default case.

Comment: I said in the title that this was in Processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a series of `if`-`else if` statements, the compiler has no way of knowing if all of them could be false. If that happens, it would reach the end of the method without returning a value, which violates its contract.

So, in this case, your `return 1` happens only if your two `if` conditions are `false`. It would be semantically equivalent to end the `if/else if` block with an `else` clause that returned a value as well:

```
int bondPositionCounter(int i, int j) {
    if (...) {
      return valueA;
    } else if (...) {
  return valueB;
    } else {
      return default;
    }
}
```

In which case you can remove the free-standing return 1 and the compiler would be happy. Essentially, for any method with a return type, *for all valid code paths* it must return a value.

If your intention is not for there to be a default return value, you could instead raise an Exception (I'd link, but you don't specify language and you could be either C/C++ or Java based on code) as the default case.

Answer (score 0):

> Without the final return line, I get an error claiming that the method
>   must return something of type int. Why is that?

because when you declare a method with a return type it is  mandatory for a method to return something

**Lets take an example**

```
public int checkHowReturnStatementWorks(){ // this method will return int

   if(condition a){ // condition going to be resolved at runtime
      return 1;
   }
   else if(condition b){
      return 2;
   }
}
```

Now suppose at runtime both the conditions are not met then what your method will return ,

> **no idea**

, the same doubt comes to compiler that is why compiler is giving  error at compiler time only that you need to add a return statement .

A piece of suggestion

```
if ((g.grid.cells[i][j].isOccupied == true)
    && (g.grid.cells[i + 1][j].isOccupied == true)) {

}
```

can be replaced by

```
if ((g.grid.cells[i][j].isOccupied) 
   && (g.grid.cells[i + 1][j].isOccupied )) {
}
```